# fractional part function ------the result is given an a book but the steps arent

Tags: functions

Suppose that period of $f(x)=T$ and period of $g(x)=S$, I am interested what is a period of $f(x)*g(x)$? period of $f(x)+g(x)$ ? What I have tried is to search in internet, and found following link for this.

Also I know that period of $sin(x)$ is $2\pi$, but what about $\sin(2x)$? Does it have period again $n\pi$, or? example is following function $y=\sin(2x) \cos(x)$ I can do following thing, namely we know that $\sin(x)/\cos(x)=\tan(x)$ and period of tangent function is $\pi$, so I can represent $y=\sin(2x)/\cos(x)$ as $y=\tan(x)×\sin(x)$,but how can calculate period of this?

Please help me.

Comment: Are $S$ and $T$ positive integers?

Answer (score 0):

If the ratio $S/T$ is a rational number, let $R$ denote the smallest common multiple of $S$ and $T$. Then, for every function $F$, $R$ is a period of the function $F(f,g)$. This applies to $F:(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ and $F:(x,y)\mapsto xy$. If the ratio $S/T$ is irrational, there is no reason to expect that $F(f,g)$ is periodic.

If $f$ has period $T$ and $\alpha\ne0$, then $f_\alpha:x\mapsto f(\alpha x)$ has period $T/|\alpha|$. For example, sine and cosine have period $2\pi$ hence $x\mapsto\sin(2x)$ has period $\pi$ and $2\pi$ is a period $x\mapsto\sin(2x)\cos(x)$ (which happens to be its smallest period).

Note that $F(f,g)$ may have a smallest period than $R$ defined above, for example, if $f=g=\sin$ (period $T=S=2\pi$) and $F:(x,y)\mapsto xy$, then the smallest period of $F(f,g)=\sin^2$ is $\frac12R=\pi$, not $R$.